# Filtering by time in Google charts

Tags: javascript, date, filter, charts, google-visualization

I'm just starting to use Google charts and I ran into a problem - I can't filter data by time (for a week, for a month, for 3 months, for six months and a year) by clicking on a button. I am creating a line chart displaying data by day. So far I have the following:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var programmaticSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
        'containerId': 'chart-container',
        'options': {
            'ui': {
                'labelStacking': 'vertical'
            }
        }
    });

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', '');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Mgr');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Glencore');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Cargill');
    data.addColumn('number', 'OZK');

    data.addRows([
        [new Date(2021, 01, 13), 6000, 7000, 5828, 7852],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 14), 1231, 2131, 3695, 9682],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 15), 2354, 8596, 7259, 9715],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 16), 7532, 5792, 3985, 3629],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 17), 6590, 7865, 2568, 5898],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 18), 2189, 2936, 9635, 6587],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 19), 9145, 7885, 8624, 6420],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 20), 7000, 8000, 9828, 7852],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 21), 2231, 3131, 5695, 9682],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 22), 3354, 9596, 6259, 9715],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 23), 8532, 4792, 5985, 3629],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 24), 7590, 6865, 3568, 5898],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 25), 3189, 4936, 8635, 6587],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 26), 10145, 8885, 7624, 6420],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 27), 7000, 8000, 6828, 7852],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 28), 2231, 3131, 4695, 9682],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 29), 4354, 2596, 7259, 9715],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 30), 5532, 4792, 3985, 3629],
        [new Date(2021, 01, 31), 6590, 9865, 2568, 5898],
        [new Date(2021, 02, 01), 3189, 5936, 9635, 6587],
        [new Date(2021, 02, 02), 7145, 8885, 9624, 6420],
        [new Date(2021, 02, 03), 9354, 10588, 12864, 13008]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chartArea: {
            left: 10,
            top: 10,
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
        },
        curveType: 'function',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            alignment: 'end'
        },
        axisFontSize: 0,
        hAxis: {
            format: 'dd.MM',
            gridlines: {
                count: 0,
                color: 'transparent'
            },
            minValue: 0
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));

    function resize() {
        var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    window.onload = resize;
    window.onresize = resize;}
```

Also tell me how to fix the position of the data in one week.
In Javascript, I don't know much yet, so I ask you for help, please

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50134335/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat , Thanks for the answer, but I have a small question for you. Can this code work on vanilla JS? If so, can you please tell me how

Comment: of course, the only non-vanilla js is the button click event. need to use `addEventListener('click', ...` instead of the jquery `.on('click', ...`

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you very much for your answer =) Can you suggest how to replace this line: var visibleRange = parseInt($(sender.target).data('range'));
I'm really just starting to figure this out, thanks =)

Comment: missed that one, try this --> `visibleRange = parseInt(sender.target.getAttribute('data-range');`

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks, you are cool ! :)

Comment: @WhiteHat May I ask you how to put the initial position of the displayed data at 1 week? Please